# Dynamics crm form load explanation

Tags: forms, process, dynamics-crm, onload, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a mscrm form, when load it for a specific clients I get an error but when I load it for other clients it works fine (no errors), the error was about process on my form which I try to hide on onload event and it is null, so I added an if before hiding it and everyting works fine:

**Solution:**

```
if (!!Xrm.Page.ui.process) {
  Xrm.Page.ui.process.setVisible(false); 
}
```

**My question is**, why it happens on some cliets forms and not all forms? it is the same form the same JS what is the reason?

Comment: when you say 'client', its web vs mobile vs chrome browser, etc? or error showing for some end user & not for others?

Comment: @ArunVinoth web - IE on-premise

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @JamesWood the error was that  Xrm.Page.ui.process is null so I added the if, BUT when the onload starts it hides the process with bo problem and a few lines later it has to show it but it's null again...

Comment: Is that double exclamation is intentional (!!) ?

Answer (score 0):

When I get those kind of problem, I put my code in a timeout like so:

```
setTimeout(function(){/*some code*/},0)
```

It put your code at the end of the stack as the last thing to do.